# How to allocate using a loop in macro VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a dataset that i would like to perform allocation on, below are the constraints:

1. Each container can only contain 310 pieces
2. We can mix colours, but the point is the maximise the 310

The code below is able to loop through every colour and split them into multiples of 310. however, when it reaches white and chalk, the code breaks.

For the code to work correctly, we should put 160 white, 120 chalk and 30 red in 1 container (in the same row).

As the code below iterates by columns, it does not work when the column next to it is a 0, and the container has not reached maximum capacity. It pushes the next available value to the next container

```
Sub sum_of_substract()
Dim i, r As Integer
Dim another As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
r = 5

Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(C" & LastRow + 1 & ":CO" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
For i = 3 To 93
While (Cells(4, i).Value) > 0
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i)) = False And Cells(4, i).Value < 310 And Cells(LastRow + 1, Value + Cells(4, i + 1).Value <= 310 Then
        Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(C" & LastRow + 1 & ":CO" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
        Cells(LastRow + 1, i).Value = Cells(4, i).Value
        Cells(4, i).Value = Cells(4, i).Value - Cells(4, i).Value
        Cells(LastRow + 1, i + 1).Value = Cells(4, i + 1).Value
        Cells(4, i + 1).Value = Cells(4, i + 1).Value - Cells(4, i + 1).Value
    
    
    
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> 0 And Cells(4, i).Value < 310 And Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value + Cells(4, i + 1).Value > 310 Then
        Cells(LastRow + 1, i + 1).Value = Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value - Cells(4, i + 1).Value
        Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(C" & LastRow + 1 & ":CO" & LastRow + 1 & ")"

    
    Else
        Cells(LastRow + 1, i).Value = 310
        Cells(4, i).Value = Cells(4, i).Value - 310
        Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(C" & LastRow + 1 & ":CO" & LastRow + 1 & ")"

    
End If
    LastRow = LastRow + 1

Wend

Next i
```

End Sub

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61qTy.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you describe your task and the problem with its solution in a little more detail. Unfortunately, the data image and the code do not answer the questions: Why is the cycle from 3 to 93? What is 93? Each container should have pieces of a different color, or you should minimize the number of different colors in one container? It looks like you need to fit all of these pieces to 53 containers, but the details matter.

Comment: thank you John! the cycle is 3 to 93 as the colours start from columns 3 to column 93. the objective here is to minimise the total number of containers used, and minimise the number of different colours in one container (we should have 6 colours max a container if possible)

Comment: I guessed that the CO column mentioned in the code is column 93. I doubted, because I don't know that many colors ([Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors) gives a table of 87 colors, up to the CK column). In other words, you can move from top to bottom and from left to right, filling each container with the remains of the next color and complementing the container with the next not yet packed color. Of course, you first need to create containers that will contain exactly 310 colors and exclude them from further processing. The task seems to be getting clearer.

Comment: oh i manipulated the data i had on hand a bit due to confidentiality which is why there are so many colours. that is right. i am able to create containers containing exactly 310 of just 1 colour. but when it involves 2 or more colours, the code doesn’t seem to work. do you have any idea on which part of the code needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm must fulfill all the conditions described in the problem:

```
Sub AllocateToConrainers()
Const CONTAINER_CAPACITY As Integer = 310
Dim rCountsRange As Range
Dim aTemp As Variant
Dim aRests() As Integer
Dim iNextConrainerCount As Integer
Dim rowNextContainer As Long
Dim iNextColor As Long
    Set rCountsRange = [C2:CO2]
Rem Clear previous results
    [A3:CO100].Clear
Rem Repack source counts to work array aRests:
    aTemp = rCountsRange.Value
    ReDim aRests(1 To UBound(aTemp, 2))
    For iNextColor = 1 To UBound(aRests)
        If Trim(aTemp(1, iNextColor)) <> vbNullString Then aRests(iNextColor) = aTemp(1, iNextColor)
    Next iNextColor
Rem When moving from top to bottom, you need to know in which line to place the result for the next container:
    rowNextContainer = 3
Rem We will immediately pack the colors that completely occupy the container - 310, 620, 930, etc. pieces:
    For iNextColor = 1 To UBound(aRests)
        While (aRests(iNextColor) Mod CONTAINER_CAPACITY = 0) _
                And (aRests(iNextColor) > 0)
            Cells(rowNextContainer, iNextColor + 2) = CONTAINER_CAPACITY
            aRests(iNextColor) = aRests(iNextColor) - CONTAINER_CAPACITY
Rem After filling each container, we write down its number and count the number of colors that it contains:
            Cells(rowNextContainer, 1) = rowNextContainer - 2
            Cells(rowNextContainer, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(RC[1]:RC[90])"
            rowNextContainer = rowNextContainer + 1
        Wend
    Next iNextColor
Rem Pack the remaining pieces moving from left to right and filling the container to the top
    iNextConrainerCount = 0
    For iNextColor = 1 To UBound(aRests)
        While aRests(iNextColor) > 0
            If iNextConrainerCount + aRests(iNextColor) < CONTAINER_CAPACITY Then
                Cells(rowNextContainer, iNextColor + 2) = aRests(iNextColor)
                iNextConrainerCount = iNextConrainerCount + aRests(iNextColor)
                aRests(iNextColor) = 0
            ElseIf iNextConrainerCount + aRests(iNextColor) = CONTAINER_CAPACITY Then
                Cells(rowNextContainer, iNextColor + 2) = aRests(iNextColor)
                aRests(iNextColor) = 0
                iNextConrainerCount = 0
                Cells(rowNextContainer, 1) = rowNextContainer - 2
                Cells(rowNextContainer, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(RC[1]:RC[90])"
                rowNextContainer = rowNextContainer + 1
            ElseIf iNextConrainerCount + aRests(iNextColor) > CONTAINER_CAPACITY Then
                Cells(rowNextContainer, iNextColor + 2) = CONTAINER_CAPACITY - iNextConrainerCount
                aRests(iNextColor) = aRests(iNextColor) - (CONTAINER_CAPACITY - iNextConrainerCount)
                iNextConrainerCount = 0
                Cells(rowNextContainer, 1) = rowNextContainer - 2
                Cells(rowNextContainer, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(RC[1]:RC[90])"
                rowNextContainer = rowNextContainer + 1
            End If
        Wend
    Next iNextColor
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you John, it works! I’d have to digest the code before coming up with some questions.